# How to make a reactive radarchart in Shiny

Tags: plot, graph, server, shiny, radar-chart

For research I'm working on a visualization of radarcharts. Since I have various topics to include in my research I want to have a reactive radarchart using Shiny where 'readers' can choose from several rows of values on what they want to see in the radar chart. However, I can't manage to do so.

My dataframe looks as follows:

```
       Power      Alliances     National Interest
max     40           40             40
min      0            0              0
lib      4            6             30
left     1           15             10
```

As I want to be able to choose between *lib* and *left* as variables in my reactive Shiny radarchart and have the radarchart itself being created by the variable's values of *Power*, *Alliances* and *National Interest*, I have created the following code:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Political Parties"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(
      inputId = "left_lib",
      label = "Argument_Type",
      choices = list("New_Left_Green"="left", "Liberal"="lib")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(column(12,plotOutput("radarPlot"))
  )))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$radarPlot <- renderPlot({

    req(input$left_lib)
    radarchart(input$left_lib,
               seg=6,
              title = "New Left / Green versus Liberal in The Netherlands",
              pcol=colors_line,
              plwd=2)
    legend(x=1.6,
           y=1.35,
           legend = rownames(left_lib[-c(1,2),]),
           bty = "n", pch=20, col=colors_line, cex=1.2, pt.cex = 3)
})})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The radarchart is created, however it does not react to choosing either *lib* or *left* in the sidepanel. How do I solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided us with your `radarChart()` function so I can't be sure, but I'm guessing that you want to substitute the value of the `sliderInput` with the ID `left_lib` somewhere in your code.  To do this, you need to use `input$left_lib` rather than `lib_left` in your server code.

You might need to add `req(input$left_lib)` at the start of your `output$radarPlot` reactive to prevent problems at start up, when `input$lib_left` hasn't been assigned a value.

Incidentally, as your code is currently written the value of `input$left_lib` will be either `"New_Left_Green"` or `"Liberal"`.  If you want to use the values `"left"` or `"lib"` in your code but keep the current text displayed to your user, you should use

`choices = list("New_Left_Green"="left", "Liberal"="lib")`

in the definition of the `sliderInput`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did include the radarchartfunction - it is in the server part of the code. I edited your remarks in my original answer. However, the Shiny server now reports that I need a dataframe as an input. By using the input$left_lib, apparently it doesn't recognize it as a dataframe anymore. Do you know if there is any way to solve this? 

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Still working on it but can't able to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having trouble with Radarcharts in Shiny right now too and suspect it might be similar issue